# Grammatically speaking what role does 'him' play in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I like him working out.

Answer (score 7):

In terms of grammatical case, *him* is marked accusative.  If you want to get into syntactic theory, then it is involved in something called [Exceptional Case Marking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECM_verb).

This Wikipedia article is a bit confusing, even if you know what ECM is.  Essentially, [him working out] is analysed as a clause, so the sentence is structured [I like [him working out]].  So, [him working out] forms a grammatical unit.  The Exceptional Case Marking is the fact that *him* is getting accusative case as a result of the verb in the main clause, even though *him* is in the subordinate clause (this normally doesn't happen).  So *him* is serving a dual role in this sentence, according to theory.

Comment: Wow, that makes my head hurt...